# How to Update row in sqlite.net pcl in windows 10 C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-10, sqlite-net

I have ID of Row then I will update other values.

I don't know how to update my values!
My Table:

```
 class MyTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Volumes { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

other information:

```
 string path;
    SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn;

    public updatepage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ccdb.sqlite");

        conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);

        conn.CreateTable<MyTable>();
    }
```

Comment: Please reference this article http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/05/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-2/ though it says to Universal app but i think it works with windows 10 app too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently started working with UWP apps, and also came across this problem. So, how to update a row using SQLite in UWP you ask? Here ya go!

```
using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
    {
        var existingUser = dbConn.Query<User>("select * from User where Id = ?", user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (existingUser != null)
        {
            existingUser.Name = user.Name;
            existingUser.Email = user.Email;
            existingUser.Username = user.Username;
            existingUser.Surname = user.Surname;
            existingUser.EmployeeNumber = user.EmployeeNumber;
            existingUser.Password = user.Password;
            dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                dbConn.Update(existingUser);
            });
        }
    }
```

The App.DB_PATH is the same as your 'path' variable. I realize that there are many different areas of interest in this answer, so if you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: You can also use LinQ to get an existing record from db: `var existingUser= await db.Table<User>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);`

Answer (score 2):

To only update a specific set of values in a row, then executing a raw SQL query would be simpler:

```
conn.Execute("UPDATE MyTable SET Price = ? Where Id = ?", 1000000, 2);
```

This assumes the input you are passing to the execute statement has been cleaned.

Comment: then immediately I need to update this to viewmodel object? any best way?